# I want to take Backup from ubuntu to other Drive from Terminal

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, filesystem, backup

My ubuntu has crashed and now I can only boot up from recovery mode where I can access only terminal. 
Is it possible for me to secure my data from Ubuntu in recovery mode?  What would be ideal is to be able to take a Backup from ubuntu to some other devices like USB drive or any hard drive. Please its urgent as all my work is stopped now and i just want backup to another device.

Your answer will highly appreciated

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You might use a Live CD to move or copy the data to an USB drive or a network share. Just boot an Ubuntu Live CD, mount the internal drive(s), plug in a USB key or a USB hard drive and copy the data.

Comment: `man cp`, also: `man dd`

Comment: Thanks for your response but How to get ubuntu Live CD ?

Comment: Thank you so much its works for me thank u bro now i can take whole backup by this Live CD its really good one.

Comment: @Mohsinkhan np, glad you managed to secure the data. If it worked well enough for you, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common technique is to use a Live CD - a standard Ubuntu Desktop (i.e. not Server) installation disc should do well enough, or perhaps a bootable USB key with installation data (made using e.g. `unetbootin`). It works with other operating systems too, at least when there is a filesystem-type support in Ubuntu (or another Live CD distro for that matter), so you may for example copy data from crashed Windows too.

Just boot the Live CD, mount the disks, plug in a USB key or an external USB hard drive, and copy the data.

This being the preferred way for many people, you may do just the same thing without GUI, so that you don't have to use a Live CD, just the OS you have installed - USB keys or drives usually pop up at `/media/` and you may use Midnight Commander (`sudo apt-get install mc`) or just `cp` the data to the external drive.